# Javascript, Extract data from JSON

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, json, extract

I have some Javascript code that parses JSON, and I want to get the "options" and "childProducts" data on o.products and cp.key.  Is there a way for me to do this efficiently without endless string parsing?

```
var spConfig = new Product.Config(
{"attributes":{
    "451":{
        "id":"451",
        "code":"package_size",
        "label":"Package size",
        "options":[
            {"id":"4",
            "label":"1 lb.",
            "oldPrice":"0",
            "products":["4562"],
            "brewsaver":"1"},
            {"id":"62",
            "label":"1 lb. crushed",
            "oldPrice":"0",
            "products":["4649"],
            "brewsaver":"1"},
            {"id":"14",
            "label":"55 lbs.",
            "oldPrice":"0",
            "products":["704"],
            "brewsaver":null}
            ]
        }
        },
    "template":"$#{price}", 
    "basePrice":"1.75",
    "oldPrice":"1.75",
    "productId":"3390",
    "chooseText":"Choose an Option...",
    "taxConfig":        {
        "includeTax":false,
        "showIncludeTax":false,
        "showBothPrices":false,
        "defaultTax":0,
        "currentTax":0,
        "inclTaxTitle":"Incl. Tax"
        },
    "childProducts":
        {
        "704":
            {
            "price":"64.99",
            "finalPrice":"64.99"
            },
        "4562":
            {
            "price":"1.75",
            "finalPrice":"1.75"
            },
        "4649":
            {
            "price":"1.75",
            "finalPrice":"1.75"
            }
        },
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The part starting with `{"attributes"` looks like valid [JSON](http://json.org), so if you isolate that (remove the `var spConfig = new Product.Config(` from the beginning and the `);` I assume is at the end) you can use [`json_decode`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) to get a nested set of PHP associative arrays.

Then it's a matter of spinning through those arrays and joining things up, no string parsing required.

Comment: Thanks for your help!  It's working!  After spending 6 hours on it (and it not working), I realized that I just needed another curly brace at the end.  Glorious!

Comment: @JenniferBorn: Good deal, glad that helped!